# Is it on topic to ask for resources?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

If I want to find out more about a certain topic but don't have a specific question because I'm so out of my depth I don't even know where to start e.g. "I have some software that I want to package as .deb? Where to find comprehensive resources/tutorials" Would that be an acceptable question to ask on this site?

I know that the tour states you should ask about **actual problems**, but in this example I do have an actual problem regarding software packaging.

I'm not sure if this is nitpicking or if I'm just overthinking this

Comment: Thank you for asking here first! I'm afraid that no, those questions aren't really a good fit here. Could be a good topic for discussion in [chat] though!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the linking to the original question (should have searched more thoroughly I guess

Comment: Don't worry about it, the search function here isn't the best. And hey, you asked on meta, that's loads of brownie points right there!